# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/acucorp/acuxui/runcbl

Tags: java, c, jvm, java-native-interface

I'm getting below mentioned error while trying to load a 64-bit native library. I checked the dependency of the library using ldd command, which is as expected. I'm not sure what could be the root cause.

```
<REMOTE>>The following Java exception occurred:
jvm 1    | <REMOTE>>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/acucorp/acuxui/runcbl
jvm 1    | <REMOTE>>    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
jvm 1    | <REMOTE>>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
jvm 1    | <REMOTE>>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1855)
jvm 1    | <REMOTE>>    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
jvm 1    | <REMOTE>>    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
jvm 1    | <REMOTE>>    at com.g1.component.coder.jni.NativeCP.init(NativeCP.java:138)
jvm 1    | <REMOTE>>    at com.g1.component.coder.jni.NativeCP.<init>(NativeCP.java:122)
jvm 1    | <REMOTE>>    at com.g1.component.coder.local.NativeCPWrapper.<init>(NativeCPWrapper.java:173)
jvm 1    | <REMOTE>>    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Comment: As the native library is written in C

Comment: @SouravGhosh He has tagged JNI check it out...

Comment: Can't you compile native library as 32 bit.. or requirement is 64 bit ??

Comment: yup requirement is 64-bit.

Comment: This might help you: [How to Load a Java Native/Dynamic Library (DLL)](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Windows.asp).

Comment: @ArjunSharma, `NoClassDefFoundError` happens whem the class loader is unable to load a class.  This has nothing to do with C or JNI.  JNI loads the shared object as part of the class intialization, but first the Java class that interfaces with JNI must be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your JNI library is looking for a class.  This is often done on startup to cache the Class lookups.

The class which is missing in your JAR is `com/acucorp/acuxui/runcbl`  I would check there is a JAR with this class in it on your class path.